# Replacing the coordinates of one point with those of a neighbouring point

Tags: arcgis-pro, point

In ArcGIS pro I have a layer with many points representing stops. Some of them have two nearby points, one point for each direction. Each point has different attributes that I need. If two points are very close to each other, is there a way or a tool to replace the coordinates of one point with those of the nearby point?

[image: Point Layer]

Comment: Have you tried the snapping tool with different tolerances to see which works best?

Comment: I don't use this personally, so can't promise it's what you need, an thus not giving at as an official answer post, but I believe the Integrate GP tool may be what you're looking for https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I was forwarded to the "pairwise integrated" tool, when I tried the integrate tool. I worked perfectly.